# KeyboardAvoidingView doesn't work properly on my app

Tags: react-native

I searched a lot about this issue and I don't know what to do now so I decided to ask here and any help would be appreciated. in my register screen I have some `input` that user must fill and for the last one I need to avoid keyboard overlay. so I used `KeyboardAvoidingView` component to solve this but as you can see in the screenshot the device keyboard still overlay my `input` (birth date).

here is my code for this screen :

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, Image, Dimensions, PixelRatio, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

import { COLORS } from '../Constants/COLORS';
import PrimaryButton from '../Components/PrimaryButton';
import PrimaryInput from '../Components/PrimaryInput';
import CheckBox from '../Components/CheckBox';

const Register = (props) => {
  const [lisenceTerm, setLisenceTerm] = useState(true);
  const [privacyPolicy, setPrivacyPolicy] = useState(true);

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/Img/office_5.jpg')} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>Join us</Text>
        </View>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <PrimaryInput placeholder='Name Surname' />
            <PrimaryInput placeholder='Your Email' />
            <PrimaryInput placeholder='Phone Number (05***)' />
            <PrimaryInput placeholder='Birth Date' />
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer}>
          <CheckBox text='Kvkk sözleşmesini okudum, kabul ediyorum' active={lisenceTerm} onPress={() => setLisenceTerm(!lisenceTerm)} />
          <CheckBox text='Kullanıcı sözleşmesini okudum, kabul ediyorum' active={privacyPolicy} onPress={() => setPrivacyPolicy(!privacyPolicy)} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
          <PrimaryButton
            buttonStyle={styles.button}
            textStyle={styles.buttonText}
            title='Register' />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '34%'
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  },
  loginContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: '100%',
    height: '71%',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    bottom: 0,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
    borderTopRightRadius: 40,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '75%',
    paddingVertical: '3%',
    marginTop: hp(1.2),
    borderRadius: hp(3.5),
    backgroundColor: COLORS.royalBlue
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: hp(3.2),
    fontFamily: 'BalooPaaji2ExtraBold',
    color: 'white'
  },
  arrow: {
    right: 20
  },
  inputContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: hp(1),
  },
  headerContainer: {
    marginTop: hp(3),
    marginBottom: hp(2),
    width: '75%',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: hp(3.5),
    fontFamily: 'BalooPaaji2Bold',
    color: COLORS.royalBlue
  },
  checkBoxContainer: {
    width: '70%',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    marginBottom: hp(1)
  }
})

export default Register;
```

and here below is the result. btw I used `behavior` and `keyboardVerticalOffset` props to control the way this component behave but still same problem.

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue in the React Native community, it's hard to work with the `KeyboardAvoidingView`. What I ended up doing is adding my custom animations to translate whatever component I need to be on top of the keyboard.

Answer (score 11):

#### Your `KeyboardAvoidingView` component must be on top of render tree

In order to scroll onto your *Join us* view, you must set a ScrollView in your `KeyboardAvoidingView` and those component must be on top of renderer.

**Try this** (based on my iOS / android setup) :

```js
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const Register = (props) => {
  const [lisenceTerm, setLisenceTerm] = useState(true);
  const [privacyPolicy, setPrivacyPolicy] = useState(true);

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        behavior={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'padding' : null}
        enabled
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.select({ ios: 80, android: 500 })}>
    <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/Img/office_5.jpg')} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>Join us</Text>
        </View>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <PrimaryInput placeholder='Name Surname' />
            <PrimaryInput placeholder='Your Email' />
            <PrimaryInput placeholder='Phone Number (05***)' />
            <PrimaryInput placeholder='Birth Date' />
          </View>
        <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer}>
          <CheckBox text='Kvkk sözleşmesini okudum, kabul ediyorum' active={lisenceTerm} onPress={() => setLisenceTerm(!lisenceTerm)} />
          <CheckBox text='Kullanıcı sözleşmesini okudum, kabul ediyorum' active={privacyPolicy} onPress={() => setPrivacyPolicy(!privacyPolicy)} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
          <PrimaryButton
            buttonStyle={styles.button}
            textStyle={styles.buttonText}
            title='Register' />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { useHeaderHeight } from "@react-navigation/elements"
import {
  Keyboard,
  Platform,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
  KeyboardAvoidingView
} from "react-native"

const Chat = () => {
    // This is the crucial variable we will place it in
    // KeyboardAvoidingView -> keyboardVerticalOffset
    const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight()
    
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }}
          behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
          // If you want the input not to stick exactly to the keyboard
          // add a const here for example headerHeight + 20
          keyboardVerticalOffset={headerHeight}
        >
          <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
            <InputWrapper>
              <RawInput />
            </InputWrapper>
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
     </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   )
}
```

Also take a look at this article it might be helpful: https://medium.com/@nickyang0501/keyboardavoidingview-not-working-properly-c413c0a200d4

Answer (score 0):

you need to install [`react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) by

```
yarn add react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view
```

and you need to wrap `KeyboardAwareScrollView` instead of `KeyboardAvoidingView`

like

```
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
<View>
...
</View
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```